# cumulative variable construction in longitudinal data set

Tags: r

**The problem:**
I would like to construct a variable that measures cumulative work experience within a person-year longitudinal data set. The problem applies to all sorts of longitudinal data sets and many variables might be constructed in this cumulative way (e.g., number of children, cumulative education, cumulative dollars spend on vacations, etc.)

**The case:**
I have a large longitudinal data set in which every row constitutes a person year. The data set contains thousands of persons (variable “ID”) followed through their lives (variable “age”), resulting in a data frame with about 1.2 million rows. One variable indicates how many months a person has worked in each person year (variable “work”). For example, when Dan was 15 years old he worked 3 months.

```
     ID age work
1   Dan  10    0
2   Dan  11    0
3   Dan  12    0
4   Dan  13    0
5   Dan  14    0
6   Dan  15    3
7   Dan  16    5
8   Dan  17    8
9   Dan  18    5
10  Dan  19   12
11 Jeff  20    0
12 Jeff  16    0
13 Jeff  17    0
14 Jeff  18    0
15 Jeff  19    0
16 Jeff  20    0
17 Jeff  21    8
18 Jeff  22   10
19 Jeff  23   12
20 Jeff  24   12
21 Jeff  25   12
22 Jeff  26   12
23 Jeff  27   12
24 Jeff  28   12
25 Jeff  29   12
```

I now want to construct a cumulative work experience variable, which adds the value of year x to year x+1. The goal is to know at each age of a person how many months they have worked in their entire carrier. The variable should look like “cumwork”.

```
     ID age work cumwork
1   Dan  10    0       0
2   Dan  11    0       0
3   Dan  12    0       0
4   Dan  13    0       0
5   Dan  14    0       0
6   Dan  15    3       3
7   Dan  16    5       8
8   Dan  17    8      16
9   Dan  18    5      21
10  Dan  19   12      33
11 Jeff  20    0       0
12 Jeff  16    0       0
13 Jeff  17    0       0
14 Jeff  18    0       0
15 Jeff  19    0       0
16 Jeff  20    0       0
17 Jeff  21    8       8
18 Jeff  22   10      18
19 Jeff  23   12      30
20 Jeff  24   12      42
21 Jeff  25   12      54
22 Jeff  26   12      66
23 Jeff  27   12      78
24 Jeff  28   12      90
25 Jeff  29   12     102
```

**A poor solution:** I can construct such a cumulative variable using the following simple loop:

```
# Generate test data set
x=data.frame(ID=c(rep("Dan",times=10),rep("Jeff",times=15)),age=c(10:20,16:29),work=c(rep(0,times=5),3,5,8,5,12,rep(0,times=6),8,10,rep(12,times=7)),stringsAsFactors=F)

# Generate cumulative work experience variable
x$cumwork=x$work

for(r in 2:nrow(x)){
  if(x$ID[r]==x$ID[r-1]){
    x$cumwork[r]=x$cumwork[r-1]+x$cumwork[r]
  }
}
```

However, my dataset has 1.2 million rows and looping through each row is highly inefficient and running this loop would take hours. Does any brilliant programmer have a suggestion of how to construct this cumulative measure most efficiently?

Many thanks in advance!

Best,
Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ave` is convenient for these types of tasks. The function you want to use with it is `cumsum`:

```
x$cumwork <- ave(x$work, x$ID, FUN = cumsum)
x
#      ID age work cumwork
# 1   Dan  10    0       0
# 2   Dan  11    0       0
# 3   Dan  12    0       0
# 4   Dan  13    0       0
# 5   Dan  14    0       0
# 6   Dan  15    3       3
# 7   Dan  16    5       8
# 8   Dan  17    8      16
# 9   Dan  18    5      21
# 10  Dan  19   12      33
# 11 Jeff  20    0       0
# 12 Jeff  16    0       0
# 13 Jeff  17    0       0
# 14 Jeff  18    0       0
# 15 Jeff  19    0       0
# 16 Jeff  20    0       0
# 17 Jeff  21    8       8
# 18 Jeff  22   10      18
# 19 Jeff  23   12      30
# 20 Jeff  24   12      42
# 21 Jeff  25   12      54
# 22 Jeff  26   12      66
# 23 Jeff  27   12      78
# 24 Jeff  28   12      90
# 25 Jeff  29   12     102
```

However, given the scale of your data, I would also strongly suggest the "data.table" package, which also gives you access to convenient syntax:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[, cumwork := cumsum(work), by = ID]
```